# How to handle nested dynamic generics in rust

Tags: generics, rust, dynamic, traits

I have a setup where I want to have a generic collection of Trait Objects, which each have a *different* generic type, (in this case represented the output of a process) but that all share a particular trait.

I have used non-generic `dyn` Trait Objects elsewhere without trouble, following the advice here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html

I would love some pointers on what is going wrong. I've put together as minimal example as I can.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

trait MyProcess {
    type Output: Output; //Each process impl has it's own unique output type
    fn process(&self, t: i32) -> Self::Output;
}

trait Output: Copy + Debug {
    fn unwrap(&self) -> i32; // But whatever the output type, I want to unwrap it to an int again!
}


//... (example trivial implementations are in the Rust Playground link)


fn main() {
    // So I define my two processes, with known at runtime types. 
    //Here I could use them both with no trouble, 
    // as long as I know which one I'm using
    let process_one = MyProcessOne {};
    let process_two = MyProcessTwo {};

    // This typing is oh so very wrong
    let both_processes: Vec<Box<dyn MyProcess<Output = dyn Output>>> =
        vec![Box::new(process_one), Box::new(process_two)];

    //Map each process to it's output. These are now of unknown type, of unknown size,
    // So it make sense to keep them in a box
    let both_outputs = both_processes
        .iter()
        .map(|p| Box::from(p.process(100)))
        .collect::<Vec<Box<dyn Output>>>();

    // The results though, are of known type
    let both_results = both_outputs
        .iter()
        .map(|p| p.unwrap().unwrap()) //Unwrap the box, then unwrap my MyOutput
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    println!(
        "Both results: {:?}, both outputs: {:?}",
        both_results, both_outputs
    );
}
```

**Link to Rust Playground:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc01da76c4a4b815ddc697392c41da41

I've played around with may variations of this, and I can't see to get Rust to play nicely with having the dynamic generic type within the dynamic generic type. The typing `Vec<Box<dyn MyProcess<Output = dyn Output>>>` seems to be pretty much nonsense, but what I am trying to say is simply "As long as it implements the Trait I really don't care"

I have also tried `MyProcess`'s `process` method returning a Box'd result, but that doesn't seem to magically cure anything because "Maybe it's upset because the output is of unknown size?", and it was at that moment I realised I was just throwing random ideas at the wall

**One thing that is important** is that I want to be able to use these processes in *non dyn* situations, and when I do I want to be able to access the specific types of the output. Some of the stuff I was looking at involved changing the trait def to something like

```
trait MyProcess {
    fn process(&self, t: i32) -> Box<dyn Output>; //Bye bye compile time knowledge of results
}
```

but this would, as far as I'm aware, stop my from using the concrete output types when I needed to

Comment: Do you want to expose both/either of the `MyProcess` and `Output` traits to clients or are they private? If they're private you might want to consider using enums instead of trait objects.

Comment: 1) Maybe you should look at generics instead of dynamic dispatch 2) `dyn Output` is not a sized type, so you can't return a value of that type (because the compiler must know its size on the stack, which it doesn't)

Comment: @isaactfa they're intended to be opened ended and public

Comment: @BlackBeans can i not somehow returned a Box'd version on the heap?

Comment: @KaiSalmon yes, since then `Box` would allocate at run-time, when it knows how much to allocate; but that's not what you do in your example, since in `MyProcess`, `process` returns `Self::Output`, and that you are asking later on `MyProcess<Output = dyn Output>`.